# Spring Boot, filter is not getting restricted to specific url

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, basic-authentication

In the spring-boot app, I have created few API calls. I want to add a filter only for few urls. The security config is as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().denyAll();

        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/user").permitAll();

    }

    AuthenticationFilter authenticationFilter() throws Exception
    {
        AuthenticationFilter filter = new AuthenticationFilter();
        return filter;
    }
}
```

I don't want filter to be applied for any api call except `/api/user` , so I denied for all urls and permitted for `/api/user`.

AuthorizationFilter class is as follows:

```
public class AuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter
{

    public AuthenticationFilter()
    {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        Enumeration<String> headerNames = request.getHeaderNames();
        while(headerNames.hasMoreElements()){
            String headerName = headerNames.nextElement();
            System.out.println("headerName " + headerName);
            System.out.println("headerVal " + request.getHeader(headerName));
        }
        chain.doFilter(request,response);
    }
}
```

This just prints all header information. Currently it is printing header information on all api calls but I want this to be printed only in case of `/api/user` and not on any other api call. Please suggest what changes shall I made?

Comment: and you could just make this more springly defining a @Component in the filter and autowiring it in your SecurityConfig :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a working solution

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class MySecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.antMatcher("/api/**");
        // add security constraints for /api/... here
    }

    /* rest of config */
}
```

[How to ignore Spring Security config for every thing except a pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29074285/how-to-ignore-spring-security-config-for-every-thing-except-a-pattern)